# Angular 2 - Angularfire 2 authentication state

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm lost in the madness of observables, promises and state. I need help to figure this out.

I'm trying to implement register/sign-in/sign-up functionality in my angular 2 application with the Angularfire2 module. I'm starting with the login functionality. I got the basics working. I can login and redirect to a new page. So far so good. In my template I'm checking if a user is logged in or not. And here starts the trouble. I having an hard time checking if the current user is logged in or not.

**Login.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  error = false;
  errorMessage = '';

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private authService:AuthService, private router:Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onLogin() {
    this.authService.loginUser(this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.router.navigate(['/'])
    )
  }

}
```

**Auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {FirebaseAuth} from 'angularfire2/index';
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth: FirebaseAuth, private router:Router) { }

  loginUser(email, password):Observable<any> {
   return this.fromFirebaseAuthPromise(this.auth.login({email,password}));
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  fromFirebaseAuthPromise(promise):Observable<any> {
    const subject = new Subject<any>();
    promise
      .then(res => {
        subject.next(res);
        subject.complete();
      },
      err => {
        subject.error(err);
        subject.complete();
      });
    return subject.asObservable();
  }


  isAuthenticated(): Observable<any> {
      const state = new Subject<any>();

      this.auth.subscribe( (user) => {
        if (user) {
          var uid = user.uid;
          console.log('the user id:' + uid)
          state.next(true)
        } else {
          console.log("no user")
          state.next(false)
        }
      })

    return state.asObservable();
  } 
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AuthInfo } from './auth/auth-info';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  isAuthenticated = false;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService) {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
        authStatus => this.isAuthenticated = authStatus
    );
   console.log('isAuthenticated:' + this.isAuthenticated);
   }

  isAuth() {
      return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<h2>
  Please login or register to use the app
</h2>

<a [routerLink]="['/login']" *ngIf="!isAuth()">Login here</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/register']" *ngIf="!isAuth()">Register here</a>

<a *ngIf="isAuth()" (click)="onLogout()" style="cursor: pointer;">Logout</a>
```

When I look at my console when loginning in I see the following results.

```
{  
  the user: id:qqsrQHB0SyeIQTbri6sYEyTTE9r2
  isAuthenticated: false
}
```

So I guess to login must be successful right? But when I check to see if authentication is true seems to fail. The *ngIf="!isAuth()" in the `HomeComponent` does not work, only if I do a hard refresh in the browser.

After a hard refresh I still see in the console:

```
{  
  the user: id:qqsrQHB0SyeIQTbri6sYEyTTE9r2
  isAuthenticated: false
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have complicated so much, this how your code should be:

**Auth.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FirebaseAuth } from 'angularfire2/index';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth: FirebaseAuth, private router:Router) { }

  loginUser(email, password) {
    return this.auth.login({email,password}) //angularfire returns a promise
  }

  loginUserObservable(email,password){ //but if still want to use an observable
    return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>> this.auth.login({email,password})) // we need to cast the Promise because for some reason Angularfire returns firebase.Promise
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }    

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<any> {
      return this.auth; //auth is already an observable
  } 
}
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AuthInfo } from './auth/auth-info';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(authResp => 
      console.log('isAuthenticated: ', authResp);
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  isAuth() {
      return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<h2>
  Please login or register to use the app
</h2>

<a [routerLink]="['/login']" *ngIf="!(isAuth() | async)">Login here</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/register']" *ngIf="!(authService.isAuthenticated() | async)">Register here</a>
<!--you can either use !(isAuth() | async) or !(authService.isAuthenticated() | async) it's up to your religion -->

<a *ngIf="isAuth() | async" (click)="onLogout()" style="cursor: pointer;">Logout</a>
```

I advise you to read this [simple guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md)